# How to convert a string containing JavaScript to usable Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a Javascript string into an actual function which I can attach to a property and reuse.

```
var fn = 'function say(something) { alert(something); }';
fn.say('hello');
fn.say('world');
```

I don't actually want to implement this... It's pure Javascript curiosity.

Comment: [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is your friend!

Comment: @adeneo you should answer in answers :D

Comment: @RaulGuiu - eval is evil, it's not a very good answer, and the real answer is that OP shouldn't do this at all.

Comment: I can see why he wouldn't though, since a quick Google search will yield results.

Comment: Before going to eval you might check out the risks associated with using it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil are good starting references

Comment: @adeneo but that is what he wants, you could add that you would not use it.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer with `eval()` in it, but you can !

Comment: I don't want to use it, I'm just curious how to do this within the Javascript language

Comment: @Andrew - You don't, you find another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do ?

Comment: Nice article on this one http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html?m=1

Comment: The difference with my question is I want it wrapped in a function. I do not want to evaluate a result, but convert my string into usable javascript. @adeneo, as I said, it's pure curiosity.

Comment: @Andrew See my answer. I try to address some of the concern around using `eval()` and why it is one of the most misunderstood features of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `eval()` function. But what you show above would not create a property on the `fn` variable. It instead just creates a function that you are assigning to `fn`. If you want to create an object with the property `say` try this instead:

```
var fn = eval('({ say: function (something) { alert(something); }})');
```

This evaluates the expression that resolves to the object containing a property named `say`. This properties value is a function that can be called like what you described above:

```
fn.say('hello');
```

Also, despite all the flak that `eval()` gets, there are actually some uses for it.

- JSON conversions
- moving definitions between namespaces
- minimization and obfuscation of JavaScript code
- dynamic code rewriting and injection
- creating metalanguages

As far as the security concerns, `eval()` itself does not add any tangible vulnerability to your code. Unless you are doing something grossly irresponsible (such as calling `eval()` on user input), there is nothing that eval introduces by its presence that wouldn't be a concern anyway. The argument often given is the security threat when evaluating content returned from the server. This threat assumes that we can't even trust the server, in which case we probably have bigger issues. Another often used argument is the man-in-the-middle attack, where someone is injecting malicious content into our resource request. Once again, if this is happening we probably have bigger concerns. If the attacker has the ability to inject malicious content into the servers response, then there is nothing preventing them from:

- returning attacker-controlled code for JavaScript loaded via <script
  src="">
- returning attacker-controlled code for JSON-P requests.
- stealing cookies and user data without altering anything
- returning attacker-controlled HTML and CSS used for phishing

The bottom line is that often the security threat arguments made for not using `eval()` are threats that will be problematic regardless of whether or not your code uses `eval()`. Despite what others might say, `eval()` is just another tool in the toolbox. Don't use it carelessly, or where another piece of code might do better. But don't disregard it entirely, even if Douglas Crockford tells you to.

Hope this helps!

References:
[Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X)
[eval() isn't evil, just misunderstood](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)